# PHP class in WordPress: assign value using get_option()

Tags: php, wordpress, class, constructor

The below is a dependency of another script, and in its current form it works just fine. It's just some info needed to authenticate an API call.

```
<?php
class getStuff {
    public $subdomain = 'somedomain';
    public $key = '123-456-789';
}
?>
```

However, the values are static. I want to use get_option() to make these values easily changeable from wp-admin. So I figured that this would make sense...

```
<?php
class getStuff {
    public $subdomain = get_option( 'option_subdomain' );
    public $key = get_option( 'option_key' );
}
?>
```

Of course, it won't work. I've read and tried a lot of examples on constructors they seem to be addressing different problems. I'm not exactly sure what to look for...

BTW, there is nothing wrong with the way information is stored in options.php - it's working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the class properties inside the constructor like this

```
class getStuff {
    public $subdomain;
    public $key;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->subdomain = get_option( 'option_subdomain' );
        $this->key = get_option( 'option_key' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works! I should have mentioned that this is a plugin I'm making, so I also added include_once("../../../wp-load.php"); at the top so the script would recognise WordPress functions.

Comment: get_option should be available when the plugin is loaded. You should not include wp-load.php. It will be included by wordpress eventually. If there are wordpress functions that are not ready you should use wordpress hooks. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/#user-contributed-notes. Here is a full list of all wordpess hooks available https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: @friendofdog could you post an example of how you used a hook for this or did you stick with the answer above?

Comment: @ProEvilz I ended up sticking with the answer above. couldn't get a hook to work in the end.